# We all know that hadoop 3.x MapReduce needs HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME in the mapred-site.xml, why does haoop 2.x not need HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME? Why?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In other words, where are the changes to HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME in hadoop 3.x?

I could not find it myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop 3 refactored the environment variables.

Hadoop 2 still had the variable, by the way, but it may have had a reasonable default

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found the initialization of HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME in libexec/hadoop-config.sh (hadoop 2) **export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX**. But after hadoop 3 refactoring, it was cancelled

Comment: Comment here https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.3.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/bin/mapred-config.sh#L30 might interest you too. HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME set there as well, and defaults to HADOOP_HOME.

Comment: @minghai See the link above from Hadoop 3. `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME="${HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME:-$HADOOP_HOME}"`